# Does asyncio.wait return only after all done_callbacks were called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Imagine the following code:

```
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

@asyncio.coroutine
def coro():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

def done_callback(future):
    print("Callback called")

@asyncio.coroutine
def run():
    future = asyncio.async(coro(), loop=loop)
    future.add_done_callback(done_callback)
    yield from asyncio.wait([future])
    print("Wait returned")

loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

Output is:

```
$ python3 /tmp/d.py 
Callback called
Wait returned
```

So `done_callback` was called before `wait` returned.

Is this guaranteed behavior? I did not find anything in documentation about this.

Is this possible situation when `done_callback` called after `wait` returned?

Answer (score 4):

With the current `asyncio` implementation, as long as `add_done_callback` is called before the event loop iteration that `coro` actually completes, all the callback scheduled with `add_done_callback` will execute before `wait` unblocks. The reason is that `asyncio.wait` internally calls `add_done_callback` on all the `Future` instances you pass to it, so it's just another callback in the callback chain for the `Task`. When your `Task` completes, `asyncio` calls `set_result` on it, which looks like this:

```
def set_result(self, result):
    """Mark the future done and set its result.

    If the future is already done when this method is called, raises
    InvalidStateError.
    """
    if self._state != _PENDING:
        raise InvalidStateError('{}: {!r}'.format(self._state, self))
    self._result = result
    self._state = _FINISHED
    self._schedule_callbacks()
```

`_schedule_callbacks` looks like this:

```
def _schedule_callbacks(self): 
    """Internal: Ask the event loop to call all callbacks.

    The callbacks are scheduled to be called as soon as possible. Also
    clears the callback list.
    """
    callbacks = self._callbacks[:]
    if not callbacks:
        return

    self._callbacks[:] = []
    for callback in callbacks:
        self._loop.call_soon(callback, self)
```

So, once the `Task` is done, `loop.call_soon` is used to schedule all the callbacks (which includes your `done_callback` function, and the callback added by `asyncio.wait`).

The event loop will process *all* the callbacks in the internal callback list in one iteration, which means both the `asyncio.wait` callback and your `done_callback` will be executed together in a single event loop iteration:

```
    # This is the only place where callbacks are actually *called*.
    # All other places just add them to ready.
    # Note: We run all currently scheduled callbacks, but not any
    # callbacks scheduled by callbacks run this time around --
    # they will be run the next time (after another I/O poll).
    # Use an idiom that is thread-safe without using locks.
    ntodo = len(self._ready)
    for i in range(ntodo):
        handle = self._ready.popleft()
        if handle._cancelled:
            continue
        if self._debug:
            t0 = self.time()
            handle._run()
```

So, as long as your `add_done_callback` ran prior to the event loop iteration where `coro` completed, you're guaranteed (at least by the current implementation) that it will run before `asyncio.wait` unblocks. However, if `add_done_callback` is executed either after `coro` completes or on the same event loop iteration that `coro` completes, it won't run until after `asyncio.wait` finishes.

I would say that if `add_done_callback` is called before `asyncio.wait`, like in your example, you can be confident it will always run before `wait` unblocks, since your callback will be ahead of the `asyncio.wait` callback in the callback chain. If you end up calling `add_done_callback` *after* `asyncio.wait` is started, it will still work for now, but theoretically the implementation could change in a way that would make it not; it could be changed to only process a limited number of callbacks on every event loop iteration, for example. I doubt that change will ever be made, but it's possible.

Comment: `So, as long as your add_done_callback ran prior to the event loop iteration where coro completed, you're guaranteed (at least by the current implementation) that it will run before asyncio.wait unblocks.`: you are describing the implementation behavior, maybe it's better not to use the word "guarantee" since it implies the official guarantee. And since if there was an official guarantee, I'm sure you would have found and mentioned it, I conclude that there's none.

Comment: "If you end up calling `add_done_callback` after `asyncio.wait` is started, it will still work for now": can you double check this please? Even with the current implementation, it seems inconsistent with this: "However, if `add_done_callback` is executed either after coro completes or on the same event loop iteration that coro completes, it won't run until after `asyncio.wait` finishes."